# change current window size on click am i doing it right?

Tags: javascript, forms, click, window, size

i want to change the size of the window to fit the page when  the user hits the submit button on a form

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PayPal Check out page</title>
</head>
<script>
</script>
<body>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="KUF8GQ9DSJJ28">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Number of Agents">Number of Agents</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="1 Agent  -">1 Agent  - $1,280.00 USD</option>
    <option value="2 Agents -">2 Agents - $2,560.00 USD</option>
    <option value="3 Agents -">3 Agents - $3,840.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="/img/order.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" onclick="window.resizeTo(1000,1000)">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" onclick="window.resizeTo(1000,1000)">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the code that i came up to but doesnt seems to do the trick

```
onclick="window.resizeTo(1000,1000)"
```

any suggestions

Comment: It shouldn't work because I don't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
 (onclick="window.open('SOMETHING.html', 'windowname', 'width=500,height=400,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=yes/no,scrollbars=yes/no,resizable=yes/no,directories=yes/no,location=yes/no')
```

So, like on submit, it's open up some window, could be the same one, but resize it how you want, etc